# Shopping cart and checkout in 1 page

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, xml, shopping-cart

How do I put shopping cart and checkout in the same page? I don't want any extensions. I want to do it in XML, but I don't how to do it.

Comment: Just to clarify you want the onepage checkout and the shopping cart page ( 'checkout/cart/index') as one?

Comment: Yes. Is there a way of putting checkout on shopping cart page, or vice Versa?

Comment: It is possible but there would be a lot of work involved and could lead to 3rd party module's not working. I wouldn't recommend it due to the complications it could cause. Instead of having them on the same page maybe look at having the cart page ajax in or something similar.

Comment: Okay thank you so much for your suggestions :)